# Is the brain more active when you do something in a dream or when awake?

Tags: sleep, dreams

If brain activity is measured using EEG, is the brain more active when asleep and dreaming of doing something or doing the same thing when awake?

Of course, if you do exercise (eg. running) when awake, it probably activates the brain much more, but what about low intensity activity, eg. dreaming of painting, etc?

Comment: How do you want to define "more active" in the EEG?